# Why convergence of the Fourier Series requires proof, and how it is proven?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The acquisition of Fourier coefficients is better known than proofs of convergence. You set $f(x)$ equal to its Fourier Series and multiplying by a trigonometric function of given frequency, and then integration on both sides will yield the coefficients.
This proof in itself is considered not to prove anything about convergence. Not even pointwise convergence?

It was much later that Dirichlet came up with a  proof for continuous functions of bounded variety (the function can be split into monotonic subintervals). This proof involves rewriting the Fourier Series to its Dirichlet-kernel form, and the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma is applied to prove pointwise convergence.

A proof of the pointwise convergence of square integrable functions was also published by Carleson in 1966.

The uniform convergence is generally proven by the Weierstrass M-Test with the help of the Parseval Equality. The criterium is the function shall be twice continuously differentiable (while confusingly other sources say it is enough ig it is once continuously differentiable, can not tell the reason why).

I also heard of proving uniform convergence with the Fejér-kernel and Césaro means.

Is the list complete and true, am I missing something?

Also, some people argue the fact that you can obtain sensible coefficient results in itself should intuitively mean the series should converge. But what interests me is the reasoning why the algebraic proof of the coefficients proves nothing about convergence and why we need these separate proofs.

Comment: This is not quite correct: "You set $f(x)$ equal to its Fourier Series and multiplying by a trigonometric function of given frequency, and then integration on both sides will yield the coefficients." What this calculation shows is that *if* such a series exists and converges to the original function, *then* the coefficients must be given by those integrals (in other words, that it is the only possible Fourier series that converges to the function); it doesn't prove that the Fourier series actually converges.

Comment: "[S]ome people argue the fact that you can obtain sensible coefficient results in itself should intuitively mean the series should converge" might be true, but that's not a valid argument. From the equation $\sqrt x=-2$, one can square both sides and obtain the "sensible value" $x=4$, but that doesn't mean it is an actual solution.

Comment: Think about Taylor series: Such an expansion makes sense for every smooth function; for them we can always write the formal expression $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$, however, this series doesn't represent $f$ for all such smooth functions (and in fact every possible thing that could go wrong does if you're unlucky in your choice of $f$: The series might diverge, it might converge but not to the function, etc.)

Comment: @GregMartin do you need to prove pointwise convergence even if you know the series exists? If you know the series exists then it should also mean the series converges, or not? I mean if it was proven that it exists, could it do anything else than convergence?

Comment: The fractional part function $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is a periodic function with period $1$; its Fourier series exists and converges everywhere, but it does not converge to $f(x)$ when $x$ is an integer. In general, changing a function at a single point (or even a measure-$0$ set of points!) will not change the Fourier series, so pointwise convergence everywhere turns out to be far too much to hope for in general.

Answer (score 4):

A few comments are in order:

- You can obtain pointwise convergence of the Fourier Series using the fact that the Fourier coefficients tend to $0$, at least for functions that are differentiable from the left and the right at a point. A simple proof is due to Paul Chernoff. Here is a discussion of that technique: https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4120/2008h/felles/FrkConv.pdf
- Dirichlet's proof using the so-called Dirichlet kernel was actually due to Fourier, and it was in his manuscript that was banned from publication for quite some time. Dirichlet probably had access to Fourier's unpublished manuscript; Dirichlet was a student of Fourier.
- Pointwise almost every convergence of the Fourier series to an $L^2$ function is way off the chart in terms of difficulty and depth.

Comment: It is new info that Fourier actually proved pointwise convergence but could not publush it. I also did not know about the proof by Paul Chernoff, but I see it alao uses the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma. Could you also elaborate on uniform convergence?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer : The Fourier Series was not discovered by Fourier. It was Euler and Clairaut who determined the coefficients based on a trigonometric series of a vibrating string problem in the latter 1700's. In order to solve the problem, the initial position of the string would have to be expanded in trigonometric functions. Most Mathematicians believed this could not be true, but Fourier argued against them. That's why Fourier was eventually prevented from published for a time. Fourier discovered the Dirichlet integral representation of the truncated series, and presented a valid proof.

Comment: so what was exactly the contribution of Fourier to the Fourier Series other than proof of convergence? And why was then the proof eventualyl named after Dirichlet?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer : Fourier's treatise on Heat Conduction introduced ideas of macroscopic math modeling of heat, and he developed his new technique of separation of variables to solve the resulting ODES using generalized Fourier series expansions. And, as I mentioned, he proved that the Fourier Series of a piecewise smooth function converges pointwise to the original function, which most people at the time believed to be false.

Comment: If Fourier was the first to prove pointwise convergence, did he also prove uniform convergence? The idea behind the Fourier Transform is that the series convergences uniformly on a chosen period, and so if this period is infinitely large, then we should be able to approximate aperiodic signals. So it is strange that Fourier did not prove uniform convergence, or did he? Or maybe it is too straightforward to even mention?

Comment: @PatrikNusszer : I'm not sure if Fourier addressed uniform convergence. I doubt it. 1830 was the rough time of Fourier's work, and that was before a real number had been properly defined! And he was dealing with functions of the time, which would be piecewise polynomial, trig, etc..

Comment: In the pointwise convergence proof it is actually not clear for what kind of Fourier coefficients the proof actually holds. You can gain differents coefficients based on from where you integrate and to which point. But you can use those coefficients independently of x to approximate the function given that x is a point on the interval of the integration. This would prove uniform convergence since in case of Taylor series, you will obtain different coefficients for every x.

Comment: @PatrikNusszer : As I mentioned, when Fourier wrote his manuscript, uniform convergence had not yet been defined. It was around 1838 that Gudermann discussed "convergence in a uniform way." Fourier was dead by then. And, a real number had not been rigorously defined either. There was no concept of an abstract function, other than piecewise polynomial and trig functions.